# adding Image to slideshow with javascript only

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a slideshow on a website i am creating and I would like to know using how could i click on a separate image and add that to the slideshow dynamically using only simple javascript

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$(".separateImage").click(function(){

   $("#slider").append("<img src='1.jpg'/>");

});
```

Comment: ok thank you but isn't this using jquery i am just need it using simple javacscipt so that along with having it i can piece through it experiment with it and commit it to memory

Answer (score 0):

Using a JavaScript framework such as jQuery (which you really should, even for small features as it makes sure that your code is cross-browser compliant):

```
$("img.addtoslide").click(function() {
  $(this).clone().appendTo("#slideshow");
});
```

The above code (which is based on jQuery syntax) would then work for all images you add to the document without having to write new code for each one.

I really recommend that you use some kind of framework for manipulating the HTML DOM. It's such messy business to try and create cross-browser safety yourself.

There are a bunch of tiny JS frameworks out there that use a syntax similar to jQuery if you're worried about the size.

Comment: No problem, but this was not the answer you were looking for?